# Monitor shell script to go with crontab -e

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi

Ive been messing around with raspberry pis now for about a month and have come abit stuck.

I have set up a media server with 1 pi (6TB) and set up osmc with another (1TB). In the media server i have sonarr and radarr set up that will organise files into films and tv shows. I have mounted the server in osmc. What I need is a script to copy only new files from one directory to another. The files will be in subfolders. I was thinking crontab with a script linked to it to search every 15 mins to update osmc folders. 1 for tv shows 1 for movies.

Any help would be much appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: So you need help with the crontab? the script? both? The crontab part is easy, but what the script has to do is far from clear (at least to me).

Comment: Have you looked into `rsync` and read the man page?  I don't think you need a *script* at all.  I think you need a fancy `rsync` command with a bunch of flags.

Comment: As mentionned by Wildcard, I think you need a rsync command line in a crontab  to feet your needs.  maybe something similar to rsync -zauv /path/sources/tree /path/destination/  then all subfolders updates modified & new files will be add/updated on destination path

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and pointing me to rsync. I made this script

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /directory/of/source/

find -type f -mmin -(time in mins) -exec rsync -zauv {} /directory/of/destination/ \;
```

Ran it on 2 test folders and all seemed to work. Just to link it to crontab and all done.